# Double label while adding a datapoint in mschart

Tags: c#, .net, charts, label, mschart

I'm writing a code in C#.Net WinForms to add label on clicking some datapoints on chart.
Before clicking the chart, the graph looks like this.

[image: Chart before click]

Now I click a datapoint between 330-340. The chart shows selected datapoint with double label (338.61). As shown below: 
[image: Chart after click]

Below is the debug output: 
[image: Debug Output]

Here is the below code for chart_mouseclick

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {               
        double mouse_Xvalue = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
        double mouse_Yvalue = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);

        DataPoint Prev_DataPoint = chart1.Series[0].Points.Select(x => x)
            .Where(x => x.XValue >= mouse_Xvalue)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(chart1.Series[0].Points.First()).First();

        DataPoint Next_DataPoint = chart1.Series[0].Points.Select(x => x)
            .Where(x => x.XValue <= mouse_Xvalue)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(chart1.Series[0].Points.Last()).Last();

        DataPoint Add_DataPoint = Math.Abs(Prev_DataPoint.XValue - mouse_Xvalue) < Math.Abs(Next_DataPoint.XValue - mouse_Xvalue) ? Prev_DataPoint : Next_DataPoint;

        int add_data_point_index = chart1.Series[0].Points.IndexOf(Add_DataPoint);

        DataPoint max = Add_DataPoint;
        for (int i = add_data_point_index - 10; i <= add_data_point_index + 10; i++)
        {
            DataPoint dp = chart1.Series[0].Points[i];

            if (dp.YValues[0] > max.YValues[0])
            {
                add_data_point_index = i;
                max = dp;
            }
        }

        chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(max);
        chart1.Series[1].Sort(PointSortOrder.Ascending, "X");

        for (int i = 0; i < chart1.Series[1].Points.Count; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[1].Points[i].Label = 
            Math.Round(chart1.Series[1].Points[i].XValue, 2).ToString();
        }                 
    }
}
```

What is wrong with the code ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: Yes. @AccessDenied

Comment: Do you have duplicate points in your array?

Comment: @AccessDenied There is no duplicate points. I have checked the 
 `Series.Point.Count` before and after adding a datapoint.  `Series.Point.Count`  increases by one only, after a click.

Comment: Seems like it does not refresh chart, but outputs original label and the one you change in code: chart1.Series[1].Points[i].Label = 
 Math.Round(chart1.Series[1].Points[i].XValue, 2).ToString();

Comment: Try to refresh it chart1.Refresh()

Comment: @AccessDenied I 'm working in winforms so there is no  `chart1.Refresh();` available.

Comment: Documentation says the different https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.refresh?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataVisualization_Charting_Chart_Refresh

Comment: @AccessDenied  it is just `Refresh();`

Comment: I tried with `Refresh()` . Its not working.

Comment: If you comment out the entirety of the last `for` loop, what happens?

Comment: @mjwills I have retested, new datapoint did not have label.

Comment: One usually will not need to Refresh a chart. - What is your question ? Don't you add a new DataPoint? Why is it suprising that it comes with a Label?? Also: Instead of Sorting the Points you can also Insert at the correct position.

Comment: @Taw  `chart1.Series[1].Points.Insert()` requires `index` value. So `chart1.Series[1].Points.Add()` will simply add and then sort ascending by `XValue`.

Comment: @TaW I have a chart with  `chart1.Series[0]`. Then I click a button that will generate some data points (with label  `XValue`) on certain condition in `chart1.Series[1]` . Along with this, I wish to add some points in `chart1.Series[1]` on clicking the chart. But when I click on chart I'm getting label with double value. This shouldn't happen. Its an error. I need to clear it.

Comment: Did you check this in the debugger? You can test the datapoint.Label. Also: You pull a DataPoint from series0 and then add it to series1 and then add labels to point in S1. I still think it is quite likely that you have a duplicate point. Test by setting the labels to `i + ". = " + all the rest..`

Comment: @TaW I have updated the question with debug output. There is no duplicate either in `Series[1]` or `Point[i].Label` .

Comment: @TaW @mjwills @AcessDenied I found that  `chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(max)` in `chart1_MouseClick` yield this error, then I changed it to `chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(max.XValue, max.YValue[0])` , this didn't give me double label error. How come `chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(max)` gives such an error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a quite interesting observation..

Let's look at the second version, which works fine for you:

```
chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(max.XValue, max.YValue[0])
```

or in short:

```
series1.Points.AddXY(x,y);
```

This is the normal way to add `DataPoints`: A **new point** is created with the two (or more) values and all other properties taken from the `Series` **defaults**.

The 'other' properties include **colors, markers and label data**, including `IsValueShownAsLabel` .

No surprises here.

Now for the original version:

```
chart1.Series[1].Points.Add(max);
```

or in short

```
series1.Points.Add(dp);
```

where `max` (or `dp`) are `DataPoints` in the **first** series (`series0`).

This behaves surprisingly different..:

One could imagine that the `DataPoint` gets **moved** (like `Controls` would be) but it isn't.  Or cloned like strings would be.

Instead **only a new reference** is created and added to `series1.Points`. This has several surprising consequences..:

- **Both references point to the same datapoint object**; so suddenly there is a point in series1 with properties taken from series0, including `IsValueShownAsLabel`!
- As both series now contain a datapoint with the same values/coordinates the chart is smart enough to display their labels slightly apart to avoid overlapping. **This is the effect you see.**
- If you now remove the datapoint from its original series0, series1 will still contain a reference to it with color, label etc as it was in series0..

So there indeed is no way to make the original version work since two references to the same point will always make the chart display the label either twice or not at all.